# how to check if the cell value is nothing or not in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

i am using grid view in vb.net.
here is code...

```
If Not DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
                i = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
                If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value <> Nothing Then
                    namebox.Text = Trim(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
                    salarybox.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                End If
End If
```

now if the cell has nothing in it then it will show the exception....
like this...

```
Operator '<>' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and 'Nothing'.
```

this is code will be called when selected cell will be changed.
i trying to get the values of the selected cell and put that in in one text box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use the `<>` operator, you should us `value IsNot Nothing` to check if it `IsNot Nothing` or inversely `Is Nothing` to check if a value `Is Nothing`.

Also the reason is that there is no comparer for the `DBNull` and `Nothing` Types so if this is the case you will need to check to see for both. Something like

```
If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso value <> DBNull.Value Then

   ''#Do something

End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value <> Nothing Then
```

to

```
If Not DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
```